# Как установить текущую дату с помощью класса Calendar в Android без времени?

Tags: android

Calendar.getInstance().getTime() возвращает дату со временем. Как получить (или перевести это) просто в дату

Comment: SimpleDateFormat

Comment: не могли бы вы указать, в какой момент использовать это?

Comment: Возможно, я могу использовать что-то еще? Мне не нужно выводить это на экран. Я сравниваю текущую дату с датой из SharedPreferences